# Confused about Visual Studio symbols

Tags: tfs

Can someone please help me with what this symbol is below in Visual Studio?
Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YceG.jpg

Comment: Which symbol?I see at least 5 different symbols in there.

Comment: The symbol that looks like a Blue Capital i

Answer (score 1):

That symbol shows that the branch has a pending uncommitted operation. For example when the branch has been moved.

Comment: Yes I did the commit and it is gone. Thank you.

Comment: This is the right answer, yet it's not marked as correct and someone's downvoted it. Well done SO, you're amazing.